# Beginning An Axis Range at a Particular Value in Plotly

Tags: plotly

I'm creating an horizontal bar chart in plotly where the numeric values are going to be percent values between -1 and 1.

As a default plotly centers these values at 0, but ideally I'd like to have the x axis begin at the baseline model score that's used to generate the values.

Here's a quick example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
data = {
    'y': ['black', 'blue', 'orange', 'brown'],
    'x': [0.25, 0.18, -.1, -.06]
}
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], orientation='h'))
```

This produces the following image:

[image]

Looks good, but I'd like to be able to specify that the axis center itself around 0.38 (or something similar), and the extend out from there in the same way it is now.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to start the axis at a specific point and keep it to a specific range you can update the x-axis and its range.

This can be done with this simple line of code:

```
fig.update_xaxes(range=[beginning value, end value])
```

In your example the code would end up looking something like this

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
data = {
    'y': ['black', 'blue', 'orange', 'brown'],
    'x': [0.25, 0.18, -.1, -.06]
}
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], orientation='h'))

fig.update_xaxes(range=[-0.5, 0.5])

fig.show()
```

And the graph would look like this:

[image]

This can also be used to center a specific value as if you set the range to have the mean of a specific value, you can have that be the center.